# An issue with my custom Windows Forms clone

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

Alright so here's the thing. The Mono Project has it's own implementation of Windows Forms and it's used to just get things working, so I decided to take it and make it better, as it seems it hasn't been maintained in years.

I can get the thing to compile and my code's up at http://github.com/MichaelTheShifter/Project-Circle, but whenever I create a test project, add a reference to the other project so if there is a crash I can see where, and when I create a new Form instance and pass it to Application.Run(), I get the following two errors in my console output.

```
[ShiftUI/XplatUI] Driver init error: Unable to find assembly 'create-keyboards, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

On my local code I've nailed it down to where the first crash is happening. It's happening in KeyboardLayouts.cs, in this area.

```
keyboard_layouts = (KeyboardLayout []) ObjFromByte("keyboard_table");
```

This is called in KeyboardLayouts.cs's LoadLayouts(). And this is my "ObjFromByte()":

```
public static object ObjFromByte(string resource) {
        var asm = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ();
        var resources = asm.GetManifestResourceNames ();
        byte[] binary = null;
        foreach (var r in resources) {
            if(r.Contains(resource)) {
                var res = asm.GetManifestResourceStream(r);
                binary = new byte[res.Length];
                res.Read(binary, 0, (int)res.Length);
                string base64s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString (binary);
                binary = Convert.FromBase64String (base64s);
                res.Close();
            }
        }
        if (binary != null) {
            MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
            memStream.Write(binary, 0, binary.Length);
            memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Object obj = (Object) binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
            return obj;
        } else {
            throw new ArgumentException ("The resource could not be found.");
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I know what's going on here - apparently, the keyboard table, when converted from binary to a .NET object, apparently has code that references an assembly called "create-keyboards", but for some odd reason I can't find that assembly ANYWHERE in the Mono repo, except for one generated by a shellscript in WinForms' resources folder, but adding an assembly reference to that doesn't fix a thing.

As for the second crash, it happens here.

```
public Widget() {
    try {
        if (WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.AutoInstall)
            if (!(SynchronizationContext.Current is WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext))
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext (new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext ());
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Console.WriteLine ("[ShiftUI] Error: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    // rest of widget constructor omitted
}
```

No idea what's going on here, but if anyone can help me with these two crashes that'd be GREATLY appreciated.

My Winforms clone is meant to make WinForms much more customizable and cool while retaining it's ease of use, and being easy to port to.

Also if there's a bug in the actual library I can go in and fix it (with help if needed) and instantly push it to my GitHub.

Also, it's worth noting I'm using MonoDevelop on Arch Linux to build this.

Comment: Mono has a developer mailing list and probably you should dig its archive first to see if anyone discussed it before.

Comment: if you run WinForms from Mono without your modifications, does it work?